# ag-grid: How to connect a custom theme?

Tags: javascript, web, ag-grid

I'm using the [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com) library for my project. The documentation says that you can add your [own theme](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-styling/). I made up my theme. [On the output](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-customise-theme) I got a sass file. How can I properly connect it to my project?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using webpack? Just reference it in your `.scss` file: `@import 'path/to/your/theme/file'.

If you want to convert `scss` to `css`, you could use this online tool: https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/. And create `css` out of it, and reference it inside `html` file.

Comment: How to correctly build a grid with a custom template? I do not want to connect a new file, but I want to build this library with a custom template.

Comment: what kind of project you have? is it angular or react or using webpack? or maybe if you could provide an example link of the kind of project structure you have, it will be more clear

Comment: I'm using dart interop.